# Failing to use selenium to find the "account already exists" error message on outlook

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

So I've started to learn selenium and bs4 to get the hang of data scraping and I thought a good learning activity would to try to sign up to an email autonomously.

I wanted to enter a name for the email like 'Jake', and then when that was taken continuously add zeros to the end of it until an email was free. My method for checking if the email was taken was to check if the 'Someone already has this email address. Try another name.' error was present.

I found that the class name for this error was "alert alert-error col-md-24".

And so I attempted to use the following command to find if it was present:

browser.find_element_by_class_name("alert alert-error col-md-24")

Selenium could never find it even when I could see the message on the tab.

I tried putting time.sleep(2) between emailtextbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) and browser.find_element_by_class_name("alert alert-error col-md-24") so the message has time to load.

```py
import requests
import selenium
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def emailcreation(namenum):
    namebeg = "Jake"
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/jakebs/webdriver/geckodriver")
    browser.get("https://signup.live.com/signup?lcid=1033&wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1563988678&rver=7.0.6737.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1%26signup%3d1%26RpsCsrfState%3dadb5869d-f5a1-d91c-ae6b-7db40ba07bf4&id=292841&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=90015&lic=1&uaid=4367c1f7dc3144e9b06c1e5365477c5e")
    emailtextbar = browser.find_element_by_id("MemberName")
    emailtextbar.send_keys(namebeg + (str(0))*namenum)
    emailtextbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep()
    emailpass = False
    while not emailpass:
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_class_name("alert alert-error col-md-24")
            print("Got here")
            for i in range(len(namebeg + (str(0)*namenum))):
                emailtextbar.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
            namenum += 1
            emailtextbar.send_keys(len(namebeg + (str(0)*namenum)))
            emailtextbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            print("Email passed")
            emailpass = True
emailcreation(0)
```

Assumed I would get this error only when the email wasn't taken but instead got it constantly.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .alert alert-error col-md-24

Thanks,
Jake